# not get record from database to itemcode have spaces although i use ltrim

Tags: .net, t-sql, c#-4.0, sql-server-2012, windows-forms-designer

**problem**

when match item code with item code have spaces by ltrim it get null result

**Details**

I make SQL query to get latest prices for customer from database

correct result is 13.5 price value

but it give me null

the problem in item code have spaces IN item code in database so that i dont

know how to match item code have spaces to get correct result

my query as following

```
string MaxPrice = @"SELECT   max(  dbo.TrxInvf.Price)
                                FROM         dbo.TrxInvF INNER JOIN
                                dbo.TrxInvH ON dbo.TrxInvF.BranchCode = dbo.TrxInvH.BranchCode AND dbo.TrxInvF.Trxtype = dbo.TrxInvH.Trxtype AND 
                                dbo.TrxInvF.TrxYear = dbo.TrxInvH.TrxYear AND dbo.TrxInvF.TrxSerial = dbo.TrxInvH.TrxSerial INNER JOIN
                                dbo.trxtypeConfig ON dbo.TrxInvF.BranchCode = dbo.trxtypeConfig.BranchCode AND dbo.TrxInvF.Trxtype = dbo.trxtypeConfig.trxtypecode
                                WHERE     (dbo.trxtypeConfig.TrxTypeID = 2) AND (dbo.trxtypeConfig.TrxKind = 1) AND (dbo.TrxInvH.TargetType = 1) AND (dbo.TrxInvH.TargetCode = " + Customercode + @") AND ( ltrim( dbo.TrxInvf.ItemCode) = '" + codeitem + @"') 
                                and TrxDate = (
                                SELECT   max(  dbo.TrxInvH.TrxDate)
                                FROM         dbo.TrxInvF INNER JOIN
                                dbo.TrxInvH ON dbo.TrxInvF.BranchCode = dbo.TrxInvH.BranchCode AND dbo.TrxInvF.Trxtype = dbo.TrxInvH.Trxtype AND 
                                dbo.TrxInvF.TrxYear = dbo.TrxInvH.TrxYear AND dbo.TrxInvF.TrxSerial = dbo.TrxInvH.TrxSerial INNER JOIN
                                dbo.trxtypeConfig ON dbo.TrxInvF.BranchCode = dbo.trxtypeConfig.BranchCode AND dbo.TrxInvF.Trxtype = dbo.trxtypeConfig.trxtypecode
                                WHERE     (dbo.trxtypeConfig.TrxTypeID = 2) AND (dbo.trxtypeConfig.TrxKind = 1) AND (dbo.TrxInvH.TargetType = 1) AND (dbo.TrxInvH.TargetCode = " + Customercode + @") AND ( ltrim (dbo.TrxInvf.ItemCode) = '" + codeitem + @"')  )";
```

the problem in item code have spaces so that i cannot match the value of item
 to get value .

so that how to match item code to get correct value from database as last

price for customers .

in debugger in visual studio 2015 my query above as following without using

variable :

```
SELECT   max(  dbo.TrxInvf.Price)
                                FROM         dbo.TrxInvF INNER JOIN
                                dbo.TrxInvH ON dbo.TrxInvF.BranchCode = dbo.TrxInvH.BranchCode AND dbo.TrxInvF.Trxtype = dbo.TrxInvH.Trxtype AND 
                                dbo.TrxInvF.TrxYear = dbo.TrxInvH.TrxYear AND dbo.TrxInvF.TrxSerial = dbo.TrxInvH.TrxSerial INNER JOIN
                                dbo.trxtypeConfig ON dbo.TrxInvF.BranchCode = dbo.trxtypeConfig.BranchCode AND dbo.TrxInvF.Trxtype = dbo.trxtypeConfig.trxtypecode
                                WHERE     (dbo.trxtypeConfig.TrxTypeID = 2) AND (dbo.trxtypeConfig.TrxKind = 1) AND (dbo.TrxInvH.TargetType = 1) AND (dbo.TrxInvH.TargetCode = 125204) AND ( ltrim( dbo.TrxInvf.ItemCode) = '            10200025') 
                                and TrxDate = (
                                SELECT   max(  dbo.TrxInvH.TrxDate)
                                FROM         dbo.TrxInvF INNER JOIN
                                dbo.TrxInvH ON dbo.TrxInvF.BranchCode = dbo.TrxInvH.BranchCode AND dbo.TrxInvF.Trxtype = dbo.TrxInvH.Trxtype AND 
                                dbo.TrxInvF.TrxYear = dbo.TrxInvH.TrxYear AND dbo.TrxInvF.TrxSerial = dbo.TrxInvH.TrxSerial INNER JOIN
                                dbo.trxtypeConfig ON dbo.TrxInvF.BranchCode = dbo.trxtypeConfig.BranchCode AND dbo.TrxInvF.Trxtype = dbo.trxtypeConfig.trxtypecode
                                WHERE     (dbo.trxtypeConfig.TrxTypeID = 2) AND (dbo.trxtypeConfig.TrxKind = 1) AND (dbo.TrxInvH.TargetType = 1) AND (dbo.TrxInvH.TargetCode = 125204) AND ( ltrim (dbo.TrxInvf.ItemCode) = '            10200025')  )
```

Comment: Your LEFT trimming your column but your value is with spaces. You need to write LTRIM('                           10200025') also. So you also need LTRIM after your = sign.

Comment: So it would be something like this `AND ( ltrim (dbo.TrxInvf.ItemCode) = LTRIM('" + codeitem + @"'))  )"` or trim your variable before by using C# TRIM(codeitem)